# Redis SignalR performance inconsistency

Tags: redis, signalr

I am looking to scale out my SignalR application, and I'm testing a few ways to do it.
When I tried "Redis" I got good  results, but unfortunately, when i sent a few bulks of messages the recieve time for each bulk is inconsistent. (varies by X10)

I tried the same with sql scaleout (also built in, in signalR) and had more stable results.

Is this normal?

Comment: It could just be a bug in the redis scaleout. You should file an issue with repro steps on github

Comment: No, it was only a request limit on my dev machine. When moving the signalR website to a proper windows server IIS it disapeared :)